# Spring Security Java Config for LDAP

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap

How do i set the URL for spring security LDAP configuration?
There are plenty of xml based examples but i cannot find a java config example to replication the below xml line. I assume it is configured in the below java code block taken from the spring guide for using a embedded ldap but how do we set a external url?

```xml
<ldap-server id="ldapServer" url="ldap://example.com:PORT/dc=example,dc=com" />
```

```java
@Override
public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource()
                .ldif("classpath:test-server.ldif");
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You simply use the `url()` method of the [`LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.ContextSourceBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/ldap/LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.ContextSourceBuilder.html#url%28java.lang.String%29)

So you would simple extend your code as follows:

```
@Override
public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource()
                .ldif("classpath:test-server.ldif")
                .url("ldap://example.com:PORT/dc=example,dc=com");
}
```

Comment: Giving examples that use .ldif() is pretty useless to anyone. Every tutorial falls back on it and it does not solve anyone's problem.